# False and/or Empty String Causes Inconsistent Pandas DataFrame.append Results

Tags: python, pandas

I've noticed that passing a Series containing an empty string ('') and/or a False value to DataFrame.append() causes it to treat `None` values inconsistently.

Can someone please tell me if I'm doing something wrong and/or not recommended?  Perhaps there is a workaround available?

### Example Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('col1','col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'))
ser = pd.Series({'col1' : None,
                 'col2' : None,
                 'col3' : None,
                 'col4' : None,
                 'col5' : None})

sum_df = df.append(ser, ignore_index=True)
print("First append = \n%s\n" % sum_df)

sum_df = sum_df.append(ser, ignore_index=True)
print("Second append = \n%s\n" % sum_df)
```

Here are my results, which I don't find suprising:

```
First append =
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

Second append =
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

### Case 1:

However, if I use the empty string ('') in `ser`, the results change.

```
ser = pd.Series({'col1' : None,
                 'col2' : None,
                 'col3' : '',
                 'col4' : None,
                 'col5' : None,
                 'col6' : None})
```

Instead of `Nan`, pd.append() returns `None` values instead.:

```
First append =
   col1  col2 col3  col4  col5  col6
0  None  None       None  None  None

Second append =
   col1  col2 col3  col4  col5  col6
0  None  None       None  None  None
1  None  None       None  None  None
```

### Case 2:

pd.append() gets even more inconsistent if both the empty string and False are values, both `None` and `NaN` values are returned:

```
ser = pd.Series({'col1' : None,
                 'col2' : None,
                 'col3' : '',
                 'col4' : False,
                 'col5' : None,
                 'col6' : None})
```

```
First append =
   col1  col2 col3   col4  col5  col6
0  None  None       False  None  None

Second append =
   col1  col2 col3   col4  col5  col6
0  None  None       False   NaN   NaN
1  None  None       False  None  None
```

### Case 3:

Changing the order of '' and False produces yet another mix of `None` and `NaN` values:

```
ser = pd.Series({'col1' : None,
                 'col2' : None,
                 'col3' : False,
                 'col4' : '',
                 'col5' : None,
                 'col6' : None})
```

```
First append =
   col1  col2   col3 col4  col5  col6
0  None  None  False       None  None

Second append =
   col1  col2   col3 col4  col5  col6
0   NaN   NaN  False       None  None
1  None  None  False       None  None
```

`Pandas.__version__ = 0.17.1`
`Python --version = 2.7.10`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Working with Missing Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html), the canonical way of representing missing values in Pandas is `np.NaN` (for performance reasons). Using `np.NaN` in place of your `None`s gets the behavior you expect. However, the best way of going about adding a row with unknown values would be the following:

```
ser = pd.Series({'col3' : ''})
```

Adding this `ser` to your dataframe yields

```
Second append = 
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6
0  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN  NaN       NaN  NaN  NaN
```

By not defining what the other columns would be, the `Series.reindex()` function automatically fills `NaN`s in for you. It's cleaner, too!

As for why you were seeing odd results in your examples, I would hazard a guess that the `(None == None) == True` and `(np.NaN == np.NaN) == False` idiosyncrasy is the root cause.

Comment: Your suggestion is a good one; I'll switch to using NaN.  I'm using Pandas as a plug-in replacement for dictionaries in the "scorekeeping" portion of my program.  Timing performance isn't an issue or me... data integrity performance definitely is. I'm now looking at converting Python-standard `None` values to NaNs, using Pandas to manipulate the data, then convert the NaNs back to `None`s for output, as my customers complain vociferously when NaNs leak into reports.  Overall, this makes we wonder if switching to Pandas was worth the headache in this case.